# VB 2013 load datagridview from a form

Tags: vb.net

I have searched the net looking for how to populate a DataGridView with the New Data "Record" that is entered into a form then save the record using the BindingNavigator.
I have a single form with the DataDridView on it and I pulled the table columns from the DataSource into the form so as to allow the people to enter new records. I then want to populate the DataGrid with the information then save it.

```
Private Sub BindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Click 

Dim RR As Integer = ACCOUNT_MOVEDDataGridView.RowCount - 2 

For RC As Integer = 0 To RR 

If ACCOUNT_MOVEDDataGridView(2, RC).Value Is DBNull.Value Then 
'' ACCOUNT_MOVEDDataGridView(2, RR).Value = ACCOUNT_MOVEDDataGridView(15,  RR).Value = 0 
End If 

Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question.  What problem are you trying to solve?  We probably need to see code to help you.

Comment: @svarg I have tried this code.

Comment: Private Sub BindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Click

        Dim RR As Integer = ACCOUNT_MOVEDDataGridView.RowCount - 2

        For RC As Integer = 0 To RR

            If ACCOUNT_MOVEDDataGridView(2, RC).Value Is DBNull.Value Then
                '' ACCOUNT_MOVEDDataGridView(2, RR).Value = 

                ACCOUNT_MOVEDDataGridView(15, RR).Value = 0

            End If
        Next

    End Sub

Comment: sorry i indented 4 times first time posting

Comment: you cannot pose code in comments. Please edit your question with your code in it

Comment: @codeMonger123  Thank you for re-posting my question and Code.  The commented out line is 2 lines of code, the first one Value =  is to default to current date, the second Value = is to default to 0

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, I was placing the code under BindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click
when it should have been under the Save Item click.

```
Private Sub ACCOUNT_MOVEDBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ACCOUNT_MOVEDBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click

            Call ACCDEF()

     Private Sub ACCDEF()
            Dim RR As Integer = ACCOUNT_MOVEDDataGridView.RowCount - 2

            For RC As Integer = 0 To RR

                If ACCOUNT_MOVEDDataGridView(2, RC).Value Is DBNull.Value Then
                    ACCOUNT_MOVEDDataGridView(2, RR).Value = Date.Now
                    ACCOUNT_MOVEDDataGridView(15, RR).Value = 0
                Else
                    ACCOUNT_MOVEDDataGridView(1, RR).Value = Date.Now

                End If
            Next
    End Sub
```

Which loads the DataGridView with the default values, Thanks to all that have looked at my problem.